# Parsing a curl json response and using response to build another request

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I am trying to build an shell script that will fetch the image url for a random XKCD comic, so that I can display it using Übersicht. Since you can only ask the XKCD API for the latest comic or a specific comic I need to:

1. Send a `GET` request to `http://xkcd.com/info.0.json`, fetch the value of the `num` element.
2. Send another request to `http://xkcd.com/XXX/info.0.json` where `XXX`is the value of  `num`.

My current command looks like this and successfully returns the comic number:

```
curl -s 'http://xkcd.com/1510/info.0.json' | grep -Eo '"num": \d+' | grep -Eo '\d+'
```

1. I haven't been able to figure out how to use capture groups with `grep`, so I need to grep the json twice. The common advice is to use `-P`, which is not supported in Mac OS X 10.10.
2. I have no idea how to read the output of grep (as `XXX`) into the second `curl -s 'http://xkcd.com/XXX/info.0.json'` command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. On OS X you can use the system Perl:

   ```
    curl -sS http://xkcd.com/info.0.json | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/.*"num": ([0-9]+).*/\1/'
   ```
2. You can save the output to a variable with command substitution:

   ```
   num=$(curl -sS http://xkcd.com/info.0.json | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/.*"num": ([0-9]+).*/\1/')
   curl -sS "http://xkcd.com/${num}/info.0.json"
   ```

   or more concisely, two-in-one, albeit not very readable:

   ```
   curl -sS "http://xkcd.com/$(curl -sS http://xkcd.com/info.0.json | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/.*"num": ([0-9]+).*/\1/')/info.0.json"
   ```

---

By the way, I highly recommend [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) as the command line JSON processor. To extract `num` with `jq`, it's as simple as

```
curl -sS http://xkcd.com/info.0.json | jq '.num'
```

and although you didn't ask for it, here's a simple one-liner with `jq` that extracts the URI of the latest image:

```
curl -sS "http://xkcd.com/$(curl -sS http://xkcd.com/info.0.json | jq '.num')/info.0.json" | jq -r '.img'
```

Example output:

```
http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/spice_girl.png
```

Comment: This works great in the Terminal, so I'm accepting it. Thanks, great work. Now I just need to get it working in Übersicht - I am getting an `octal escape sequence` error.

Comment: @SamuelLindblom I can't see any octal escape sequence in my commands though. And I don't use Übersicht — can you explain which step goes wrong in detail? (If you're not sure, you can break down the pipeline and test separately.)